# Async Await in Cassandra using Node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, async-await

I want to execute this query which I have written in cql by using Async Await functions.

```
client.execute('select * from users).then(res => {
    console.log('hello user');
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Can someone tell me the exact translation of this query into Async Await functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it but I am not deleting this post as it maybe can help somebody.

```
app.get('/', async(req,res) => {
    const res1 = await client.execute('select * from users);
    var user = res1.rows[0];
    console.log('successfull');
});
```